# How do I find the highest salary from each department using SUBQUERIES

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I'm really new to this and this particular question has been bugging me for days. I do know there are similar questions to this but I kept wondering how it would be done in subqueries.

SALARY TABLE
[Emp_ID]  [SalaryPM]
001    | 10,500
002    | 50,000
003    | 8,000
004    | 10,000

```
DEPT TABLE
```

[Emp_ID] [Dept_ID]
001     |   A
002     |   B
003     |   C
004     |   C

### I want it to look like this

[Emp_ID] [Dept_ID] [SalaryPM]
001     | A       | 10,000
002     | B       | 50,000
004     | C       | 10,000

### What I have tried so far, but it only gives the highest salary of the employee##

SELECT * FROM DEPT
WHERE EMP_ID IN
(SELECT Emp_ID
FROM SALARY
WHERE SalaryPM = (SELECT MAX(SalaryPM)
FROM SALARY));

Comment: Why do you want to do that specifically with subqueries? It is clearly not the best way to proceed.

Comment: Without trying anything, of course it's been bugging you for days.  At least try something.

Comment: I want to retrieve data from two tables without using JOINS (GMB)

Comment: (ERIC) So sorry for that, I have re edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Would this qualify as a subquery solution?

```
select *
from (
    select s.*, e.deptid, 
        rank() over(partition by e.dept order by s.salaries desc) rn
    from employees e
    inner join salaries s on s.id = e.id
) rn
where rn = 1
```

Note: your does not look good. The data you are showing suggests a 1-1 relationship between the two tables (wich I called `employees` and `salaries`): if so, both tables should be combined in a single table.

Comment: Yes but how about without the joins, so you use WHERE Emp_id IN (SELECT Emp_id FROM DEPT)

Answer (score 0):

I would be good to know what do you mean by "using subqueries" ;)

here's another solution using subquery in the SELECT clause

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.deptid,
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(s.salary)
        FROM
            my_salaries s
        WHERE
            s.id = d.id
    ) max_salary
FROM
    my_departments d;
```

here's solution without joining tables (IMHO not joining tables is just overcomplicating things). Why 'not using join' is so important for you?

```
SELECT
    sub.id,
    MAX(sub.deptid),
    MAX(sub.salary)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            d.id,
            d.deptid,
            NULL salary
        FROM
            my_departments d
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            s.id,
            NULL deptid,
            s.salary
        FROM
            my_salaries s
    ) sub
GROUP BY
    sub.id
ORDER BY
    sub.id;
```

Comment: Without using join statement

Comment: May I know what is (my_) used for. Thank you

Comment: @chirx - sure,I already had tables called salaries and departments on my schema, so I just created new tables with my_ prefix

Comment: @chirx btw. I added another solution to my answer